# How can i get reputation if i am not permitted to answer and participate in superuser network?

Tags: support, reputation

I have a problem with the Super User (and Stack Exchange) account limitation system. Currently I am not allowed to answer in any question. They say I need to reach 50 reputation points.

The problem is I can't reach that number of points if I am not allowed to answer. So how can I gain reputation if the only thing I can do here is to ask questions?

I have the same remark about Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, I am just a viewer i feel bad about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### They say I need firstly to reach 50 reputation points

50 rep is required to comment not to answer questions.

You can always answer questions (as long as you haven't been [answer banned](https://superuser.com/help/answer-bans) for poor quality answers).

Please take some time to read the following as it will help you understand the site better:

- You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).
- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)
- [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).
- [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes exactly this is what i wanted to say i can't comment on other's posts, i didn't notice i can answer because i always try to add a comment and they prevent me to do so, it is frustrating.

Comment: So answer questions that don't require you comment and you are comfortable answering

Answer (score 3):

Note that you may have encountered a [*protected* question](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). Some questions that have been observed to attract multiple poor answers by very new users can be protected, either automatically or by a >15K user. This might happen, for example, when a question describing a common problems gets linked to from some popular place, bringing lots of users in who are unfamiliar with our system.

To answer a protected question, you need to have at least 10 rep on this site. Most questions, fortunately, are not protected. Absent protection, any user in good standing may submit an answer using the text box at the very bottom of the page.

Once you get 50 reputation, you'll be able to comment using the "add a comment" link below each post, but please note that if you have a complete solution to a problem, you should answer instead of commenting.

Comment: So you are saying i don't need to comment but firstly to answer directly to the topic providing my own solution to the problems but i am not in confort with that, because the most of times i just need to comment to ask for further explanations, this is why i was here for a long time with no rep points at all.

Comment: Ah, if you're asking for elaboration, you should indeed comment rather than answer. Until you gain the reputation to do that, you can answer high-quality questions that already have all the information necessary - there are plenty!

Comment: @P.Kod If your not comfortable with a topic you really shouldn't be answering that question

Comment: @Ramhound This is what i said when you are not comfortable with a topic you shouldn't answer but you may still want to comment one of the provided answers to learn more/ ask the authors about explanations.

Comment: @P.Kod Your welcome to do that when you have enough reputation to do so, but keep it mind, comments are not meant to be around forever or to be used for discussions.  So really you shouldn't even use comments unless your clarifying an existing answer.

Comment: Additionally, you cannot gain reputation from comments, and commentary submitted as an answer will just result in (a loss of reputation, the answer being deleted, and eventually result in an answer ban)